# What is our stance on questions about assistive technology recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

What is our stance on questions about assistive technology recommendations? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/7256/43):

> Question: Are there any tools/aids which can help deaf and mute
>   people?
>
> Are there any tools/aids which can help deaf and mute (both at the
>   same time) people do some work and make a living?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think asking for recommendations is acceptable since recommendations are inherently opinion polls, and they're very ephemeral. A good recommendation today might be a terrible recommendation next year.

But simply asking what technology is out there, what the pros and cons are, etc. seems fine to me. The example question definitely looks okay to me.